# Нужна ли запятая на стыке союзов?

Tags: пунктуация

Но (,) как это ни горько признать, отметим, что переход к новой концепции совсем непрост ввиду мощного противодействия влиятельных сановников...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для присоединительного союза НО возможны **оба варианта,** при этом  постановка запятой определяет отнесенность союза к главной или придаточной части (**это решение автора**) и зависит как от семантики, так и от структуры предложения (распространенность, наличие паузы в речи).

**Обычно нет необходимости  в постановке запятой** после  присоединительных союзов перед подчинительными союзами , так как в этом случае придаточная часть приобретает вставочный характер (это также надо учитывать при авторском обособлении союза).

Но, как ни искренно хотела Анна страдать, она не страдала (Л. Н. Толстой).

Но как ни напрягался князь, как ни вслушивался, он буквально ничего не мог понять (Ф. М. Достоевский).

Но как ни хорошо знал Пьер эту историю, он теперь прислушался к ней, как к чему-то новому (Л. Н. Толстой).

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: На мой взгляд ''как это ни горько признать" вводное предложение . Запятая должна стоять именно на этом основании.

Comment: Как ни..., где ни...-уступительные союзы, это придаточное уступительное, а не вводное предложение.

Comment: Людмила, а разве вводные предложения не могут вводится союзами и союзными словами?

Answer (score 1):

Попробую ответить сама (кажется, нашла решение). Первое и самое главное условие: запятая ставится, если при изъятии придаточного предложения смысл и структура основного не нарушается. Здесь такое изъятие возможно. *Но отметим, что переход к новой концепции совсем непрост ввиду мощного противодействия влиятельных сановников.*

Вторым условием является наличие или отсутствие паузы между сочинительным союзом и подчинительным: если пауза есть, запятая ставится, при ее отсутствии - нет.

Более подробно можно посмотреть [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140).